# Software to force me to get out of the computer in a predefined time

Tags: windows-10, time-management

I am using Ubuntu and Windows 10. I usually spend most of the time sitting in front of my laptop. So it may, and probably has a bad impact on my health. So when I use Ubuntu I use [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/12/take-break-helps-you-to-actually-take.html), and it makes my screen upside down for a defined time so by forcing me to take a break. When I use Windows sometimes I forget about time and sitting a long period. I found [this post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/software-forcing-me-to-make-rest-breaks-during-work-at-the-computer) but it didn't help me to find the one I am looking for.

Is there a software (for Windows 10) which change the screen orientation or locking, dimming or something like that other than just showing me a notification or a sound?

Comment: I'm not sure if you checked out Workwave enough, I have actually and you can block the screen and force yourself off the pc with this software. Please check out the software and read through the settings of the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Software forcing me to make rest breaks during work at the computer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/software-forcing-me-to-make-rest-breaks-during-work-at-the-computer)